# transform Collection<myClass> to Collection<String>

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons, anonymous-class

I trying to implement functionally similar to [CollectionUtils transform (Apache Commons Collections)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html)

```
class CollectionUtils {

    public static void transformerModifier(Collection<MyClass> myCollection) {
        // How should I implement this method in order that 
        // output from the line 1 and line 2 will be the same ? 
    }

    public static List<String> transform(Collection<MyClass> myCollection) {
        List<String> strCollection = new LinkedList<>();
        for (MyClass item : myCollection) {
            strCollection.add(item.getName());
        }
        return strCollection;
    }
}
```

```
class myClass { 
    private String name; 
    private int value; 

    myClass( String name, int value) {
        this.name = name ; 
        this.value = value; 
    }

    public String toString(){
        return new String(name+ ":" + value ) ; 
    }
}
```

```
class MyClassCollection{
    private List<myClass> list ; 

    myClassCollection(List<myClass> list){
        this.list = list; 
    }

    List<myClass> collection(){
        return list.clone(); 
    }

}
```

```
public class TestClass{

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
        list.add(new myClass("John", 12);
        list.add(new myClass("Mike", 16);
        list.add(new myClass("Eric", 13);
        list.add(new myClass("Mark", 142);
        list.add(new myClass("Alex", 112);

        MyClassCollection myOjb = new MyClassCollection(list );
        CollectionUtils.transformerModifier(myObj.collection() ); 
        List<MyClass> myList = CollectionUtils.transform(myObj.collection()); 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myObj.collection().toArray)); // line 1
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList.toArray));            // line 2
    } 

}
```

```
output: [John,Mike,Eric,Mark,Alex] // output after line 1 
output: [John,Mike,Eric,Mark,Alex] // should be output after line 2
```

My question is it possible to implement method transformerModifier in the way that it will change collection of the object myObj so that myObj.collection() return not the `List<myClass>` but the List of `List<String>` ( where string is the data from `private String name` data member of `myClass` ) ?

My guess is that the solution should be through anonymous class. However, I didn't understand yet how should I implement it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public interface Converter<I, O> {

    void tranformer(List list);

    O retriever(I obj);
}
```

_

```
  public static <I, O> void transform(Converter<I, O> converter, List inputList) {
        Iterator<I> it = inputList.iterator();
        List list = new LinkedList<>();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            list.add(converter.retriever(it.next()));
        }
        converter.tranformer(list);
    }
```

_

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
        list.add(new myClass("John", 12);
        list.add(new myClass("Mike", 16);
        list.add(new myClass("Eric", 13);
        list.add(new myClass("Mark", 142);
        list.add(new myClass("Alex", 112);

        MyClassCollection myclasscollection = new MyClassCollection(list); 
        final List collectionList = myclasscollection.collection(); 
        CollectionUtils.transform(new Converter<myClass, String>() {
            @Override
            public void tranformer(List list) {
                employeeList.clear();
                employeeList.addAll(list);
            }

            @Override
            public String retriever(myClass obj) {
                return obj.name; // make the data member public or add getter 
            }
        }, collectionList);

 collectionList.get(0).toString.toLowerCase(); 

}
```

This isn't fully what you need but I bet this isn't bad alternative. Please, notice that could output collection collectionList will be collection of objects ( not String ), however, you can access to methods of the String data type   just to right like this  `collectionList.get(0).toString.toLowerCase();` Hope this help.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Java 8, you could make use of `stream`s and `map()` to do something like this:

```
List<MyClass> myClassList = new ArrayList<>();
//add your items to myClassList here

List<String> names = myClassList.stream().map(MyClass::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
//names will now consist of a List of all the names associated with
//each of the MyClass objects within myClassList in the same order
```

This solution makes use of Method Reference as well `MyClass::getName`.  This calls the `getName` method on each object in the `stream` `map`ping it to its respective spot in the transformed stream using `.map()`.

Next it uses `.collect()` to bring it back from a `stream` to a `list` using `Collectors.toList()`.

If you are working with a lot of objects within `myClassList`, this process can be sped up using `.parallelStream()` instead of `.stream()`, but if you are not working with a large amount of data, you may see a reduction in performance with `.parallelStream()`.  It all depends on how many objects you expect to be present within the `List`.